# Bottom navigation menu based on the user logged in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview, android-menu

Is it possible to hide/show the bottom navigation menu item in Kotlin based on the user logged in?
I have some items in the bottom navigation which I do not want to show to all the users.

Edit:
Here is my code.

I want to remove `@+id/navigation_products` from the menu when the users are not, for example, abc and xyz.

bottom_nav_menu.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_vector_dashboard"
        android:title="@string/title_dashboard" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_products"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_vector_products"
        android:title="@string/title_products" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_orders"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_vector_orders"
        android:title="@string/title_orders" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_sold_products"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_vector_sold_products"
        android:title="@string/title_sold_products" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_orders_by_status"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_vector_sold_products"
        android:title="@string/title_orders_by_status" />
</menu>
```

mobile_navigation.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_dashboard">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:name="com.ui.fragments.DashboardFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_dashboard"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_products"
        android:name="com.ui.fragments.ProductsFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_products"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_products" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_orders"
        android:name="com.ui.fragments.OrdersFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_orders"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_orders" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_sold_products"
        android:name="com.ui.fragments.SoldProductsFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_sold_products"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_sold_products" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_orders_by_status"
        android:name="com.ui.fragments.OrdersByStatusFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_orders_by_status"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_sold_products" />
</navigation>
```

DashboardActivity.kt

```
class DashboardActivity : BaseActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard)

        supportActionBar!!.setBackgroundDrawable(
            ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                this@DashboardActivity,
                R.drawable.app_gradient_color_background
            )
        )

        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
      
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_products,
                R.id.navigation_dashboard,
                R.id.navigation_orders,
                R.id.navigation_sold_products,
                R.id.navigation_orders_by_status
            )
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        doubleBackToExit()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can launch the app with the entire menu items and then remove items based on the logged-in user:

Here is an extension function to the `BottonNavigationView` that can remove an item with a certain id

```
fun BottomNavigationView.removeItem(id: Int) {
    if (menu.findItem(id) != null)
        menu.removeItem(id)
}
```

And then you can apply it on the logged-in user:

```
// check logged-in user
when (loggdUser) {

    user_a -> {
        bottomNavView.removeItem(R.id.menu_item_id1)
        bottomNavView.removeItem(R.id.menu_item_id2)
    }

    user_b -> bottomNavView.removeItem(R.id.menu_item_id2)

}
```

`menu_item_idx` is supposed menu ids & `bottomNavView` is the `BottomNavigationView` instance; so replace them to yours

**UPDATE:**

Testing that in the code:

```
class DashboardActivity : BaseActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard)

        supportActionBar!!.setBackgroundDrawable(
            ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                this@DashboardActivity,
                R.drawable.app_gradient_color_background
            )
        )

        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
      
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_products,
                R.id.navigation_dashboard,
                R.id.navigation_orders,
                R.id.navigation_sold_products,
                R.id.navigation_orders_by_status
            )
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

        
        val loggdUser = "user_a"
        // check logged-in user
        when (loggdUser) {

            "user_a" -> {
                navView.removeItem(R.id.navigation_orders_by_status)
                navView.removeItem(R.id.navigation_orders)
            }

            "user_b" -> navView.removeItem(R.id.navigation_orders)

        }

    }


    fun BottomNavigationView.removeItem(id: Int) {
        if (menu.findItem(id) != null)
            menu.removeItem(id)
    }


}
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for but I am not able to make the changes to my code. I have added my code to the question. Could you help me change the code. Thanks.

Comment: @Codist I can't see where you check the logged-in user from the provided code ... but you can use the `when` block added in the answer, and then replace `bottomNavView` with `navView` as this is yours .. and replace `R.id.menu_item_idx` with a valid menu id from your menu like `R.id.navigation_dashboard` or `R.id.navigation_products`

Comment: Currently, I do not have it. I am a beginner and I do not know how to do that.

Comment: Could you help me change my code to accomplish it?

Comment: @Codist For your current code, you can not check for a logged in user, but you can replace that with some `String` for testing .. please check UPDATE section in the answer

Comment: Can you check if there is any mistake in `when` part? I get `Unresolved reference: bottomNavView` error.

Comment: Sorry replace it with navView

Comment: Great. It did work as expected. The only thing that left is to check the username that is stored in the `firestore`. I will try that myself. Thanks.

Comment: How can I change the code to work this 'when' the user is 'not equal to' '"user_a"?

Comment: You can change the `loggdUser` variable to the username as you like `user_b` and put a corresponding value in the `when` block... for any other user you can use `else {}` statement within the `when` block

Comment: I have noticed that removing the item has a downside. On launching the app, sometimes, it shows all the menu (item) for a moment before it removes and the user can get a glimpse of it. Is there a way to add the menu (items) instead of removing them, Is that possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible. For such a logic, you have to change the bottomnavigation menu dynamically. To make things easier, you can add the following dependency:

```
// Event Bus
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.2.0'
```

Then let's assume the following:

### Activity xml

```
<layout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".framework.ui.view.MainActivity">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:name="com.example.app.framework.utils.MainNavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/wrapContent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_main" />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/default_menu" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

### default_menu.xml (menu for all users)

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@id/homeFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/child_selector_home"
        android:title="@string/bottom_nav_home" />

    <item
        android:id="@id/nav_shop"
        android:icon="@drawable/child_selector_shop"
        android:title="@string/bottom_nav_shop" />

    <item
        android:id="@id/userLoggedOutFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/child_selector_profil"
        android:title="@string/bottom_nav_profil" />

</menu>
```

### logged_in_menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@id/homeFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/child_selector_home"
        android:title="@string/bottom_nav_home"/>

    <item
        android:id="@id/documentsFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/child_selector_documents"
        android:title="@string/bottom_nav_documents"/>

    <item
        android:id="@id/nav_shop"
        android:icon="@drawable/child_selector_shop"
        android:title="@string/bottom_nav_shop"/>

    <item
        android:id="@id/shoppingCartFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/child_selector_shopping_cart"
        android:title="@string/bottom_nav_shopping_cart" />

    <item
        android:id="@id/userLoggedInFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/child_selector_profil"
        android:title="@string/bottom_nav_profil"/>

</menu>
```

### Activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    // Basic Binding Stuff
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate()
       binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
       setContentView(binding.root)
   }


    @Subscribe
    fun onLoginLogOutEvent(event: LogInOutEvent) {
        if (event.isLoggedIn) signInUserBottomNav() else signOutUserBottomNav()
    }


    private fun setUpBottomNav(newMenu: Int) {
        with(binding.bottomNavigationView) {
            menu.clear()
            inflateMenu(newMenu)
            setupWithNavController(findNavController(R.id.fragment_container))
            // fix blinking when re selecting bottom nav item
            setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener {}
        }
    }

    private fun signOutUserBottomNav() {
        setUpBottomNav(R.menu.default_menu.xml)
    }

    private fun signInUserBottomNav() {
        setUpBottomNav(R.menu.logged_in_menu)
    }
}
```

### Event

```
value class LogInOutEvent(
    val isLoggedIn: Boolean,
)
```

The activity does the following: Every time you send an event via your event bus from either a fragment or an activity, `onLoginOutEvent()` gets executed. Here it checks if you either send an Event where the user is logged in or not. You can use it so:

### SomeFragment

```
class SomeFragment : Fragment() {
   override fun onViewCreated() {
      super.onViewCreated()

   }

   private fun doStuff() {
      // here you do your stuff and decide whether to change the bottom nav or not
      Eventbus.getDefault().post(LoginOutevent(isLoggedin = true))
   }

}
```